# How can I fix material ui errors in console?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using material ui for my react project and its working very fine but it gives me these errors in console to which I dont understand because I didn't code them in my components

```
index.js:1 Warning: React does not recognize the `disableElevation` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `disableelevation` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
    in a (created by LinkAnchor)
    in LinkAnchor (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Link (created by Context.Consumer)
    in NavLink (at Sidenav.js:81)
    in div (created by ForwardRef(ButtonGroup))
    in div (created by Transition)
    in Transition (created by ForwardRef(Collapse))
    in ForwardRef(Collapse) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Collapse)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(List)) (at Sidenav.js:65)
    in Transition (created by ForwardRef(Slide))
    in div (created by ForwardRef(Modal))
console.<computed> @ index.js:1
index.js:1 Warning: React does not recognize the `disableFocusRipple` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `disablefocusripple` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
    in a (created by LinkAnchor)
    in LinkAnchor (created by Context.Consumer)
    in ForwardRef(ExpansionPanelDetails) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(ExpansionPanelDetails)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(ExpansionPanelDetails)) (at Sidenav.js:74)
    in div (created by ForwardRef(ExpansionPanel))
    in div (created by Transition)
    in div (created by ForwardRef(Paper))
    in ForwardRef(Paper) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)) (created by Transition)
    in Transition (created by ForwardRef(Slide))
    in ForwardRef(Slide) (created by TrapFocus)
    in TrapFocus (created by ForwardRef(Modal))
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at App.js:19)
    in div (at App.js:18)
    in App (at src/index.js:9)
console.<computed> @ index.js:1
index.js:1 Warning: React does not recognize the `disableRipple` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `disableripple` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
    in a (created by LinkAnchor)
    in LinkAnchor (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Link (created by Context.Consumer)
    in NavLink (at Sidenav.js:81)
    in ul (created by ForwardRef(List))
    in ForwardRef(List) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(List)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(List)) (at Sidenav.js:65)
    in div (at Sidenav.js:57)
    in App (at src/index.js:9)
console.<computed> @ index.js:1
index.js:1 Warning: React does not recognize the `fullWidth` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `fullwidth` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
    in a (created by LinkAnchor)
    in LinkAnchor (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Link (created by Context.Consumer)
    in NavLink (at Sidenav.js:81)
    in div (created by ForwardRef(ButtonGroup))
    in ForwardRef(ButtonGroup) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(ButtonGroup)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(ButtonGroup)) (at Sidenav.js:75)
    in div (created by ForwardRef(ExpansionPanelDetails))
    in div (created by Transition)
    in div (created by Transition)
    in Transition (created by ForwardRef(Collapse))
    in ForwardRef(Collapse) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Collapse)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Collapse)) (created by ForwardRef(ExpansionPanel))
console.<computed> @ index.js:1
```

I even removed the react strictmode and they're still there . Has anyone fixed this kinda issue ?

Comment: Please show the code for `Sidenav.js`. Even better would be to reproduce your problem in a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new).

Comment: What's your React and MUI version?

Comment: What components are you importing and using from material-ui? Also, can you show us the code how you used those components in your code?

Comment: I ran into this when using the Popover component in MUI 4.9.x. Looking at the component tree, the Modal was passing its props to the popover (disableRipple, fullWidth, disableElevation, disableFocusRipple), causing this exact issue. Looking at the source, there was no way to keep these props from being passed (that I could see). The only way I could get rid of these errors, was to switch to a Modal/Paper setup (not ideal).

Comment: @DBrown This https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/23041 issue looks similar. But it is still open. You can follow that issue and maybe create a new one (if yours is different).

Comment: That issue is an actual typing issue with TS for a missing prop, possibly from the Modal object; it is a different issue all together. I was commenting to show a cause for this combination of errors for anyone who runs into the same issue. AFAIK this issue doesn’t exist in the latest branch, so we can probably assume it’s due to a component transition between major releases.